# change leaflet method latlng to lnglat

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet, google-earth

i use google earth to create polygon area and save it into kml. the kml coordinate format is longitude-latitude. But Leaflet format is latitude-longitude

here's the example

```
 var statesData = 
{"type":"FeatureCollection",
"features":[
    {"type":"Feature","id":"72","properties":
{"name":"Puerto Rico","density":1082 },
"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[
 [109.2299584026405,-7.251704676336486],109.2376875108402,-7.255838896277941],[109.2454156842918,-7.264692077983154]]]}]};
```

anyone know how to convert Lat-Long to Long-Lat in this javascript or maybe save kml file to Lat-Long format?

i have more than 200 rows coordinate and it will be so much not efficient if i switch manually

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sample you show follows a standard GeoJSON format (with a small mistake, but I guess it is just a typo).

Leaflet automatically does the conversion when you parse that GeoJSON data through the [`L.geoJSON()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#geojson) factory.

You can also directly use your KML file, e.g. by using the [leaflet-omnivore](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-omnivore) plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to **accept** the answer that solved your issue.